# aggregate request MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, aggregation-framework

I'd like get a multiple fields in a collection list with a condition. I tried a aggregate request but i have an error.

My request

`db.people.aggregate({$match:{createdDate:{$exists:true},"ad":"noc2"}},{$group:{value2:$value2}});`

My Json :

```
    db.test.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51e7dd16d2f8db27b56ea282"),
        "ad" : "noc2",
        "list" : {
                "p45" : {
                        "id" : "p45",
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                },
                "p6" : {
                        "id" : "p6"
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                },
                "p4578" : {
                       "id" : "4578"
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 100,
                        "value2" : 489
                }
        }
}
```

I want to get this json, for example, in result :

```
{id:p45,value:587},{id:p4578,value:47},{id:p6,value:2}
```

Comment: What Error are you getting?

Comment: Please change your `result` to a  readable Json.

Comment: the result error is "Fri Jul 19 12:47:05.623 JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: $value2 is not defined"

Comment: i haven't tried to replicate this error but just a quick test to see if it works. can you try enclosing the $value2 in a double quote? like  `db.people.aggregate({$match:{createdDate:{$exists:true},"ad":"noc2"}},{$group:{value2:"$value2"}});`

Comment: I have this error with quote : "Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:9)
    at (shell):1:11
Fri Jul 19 13:41:48.026 JavaScript execution failed: aggregate failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: the group aggregate field 'value2' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
        "code" : 15951,
        "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L898"

Comment: You don't have to replicate this error, why ? Did you manage to run ?

Comment: Can you show the JSON docs matching the results you want to get? The sample JSON you give seems to be different from the sample result you want to get.

Comment: as this : {id:p45,value:587},{id:p4578,value:47},{id:p6,value:2}

Comment: Are you counting the number of times value2 occurs for each id field? What exactly is the result you want to get? While you have given us an example of the format of the result, that does not show what type of aggregation it is that you want to perform here in the example. Is it that you want to count the number of occurrences or you want to sum out the values, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues with your sample document and aggregation:

- the sample doc will not match your aggregation query because you are matching on `createdDate` field existing
- the [`$group()` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/) works on a document level and needs an `_id` field to group by
- your `list` field is an embedded document, not an array
- aside from formatting, there is no obvious way to relate the sample values to the calculated result you are looking for

Here is an adjusted example document with the `list` as an array as well as some unique values for each item that happen to add up to the `value` numbers you mentioned:

```
db.people.insert({
        "ad" : "noc2",
        "createdDate" : ISODate(),
        "list" : [
                {
                        "id" : "p45",
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 77,
                        "value2" : 489
                },
                {
                        "id" : "p6",
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 20,
                        "value1" : 20,
                        "value2" : 7
                },
                {
                       "id" : "4578",
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-18T12:18:30.568Z"),
                        "value3" : 21,
                        "value1" : 300,
                        "value2" : -319
                }
        ]
})
```

You can now use the [`$unwind` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/) to extract the matching subdocuments.

It is unclear from the current question description what `$group` operation you are trying to achieve and whether you actually need `$group`.

Here is an example using the Aggregation Framework to [`$add`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/add/) (total) the three values for each list item:

```
db.people.aggregate(

    // Find relevant docs (can use index if available)
    { $match: {
        createdDate: { $exists:true },
        "ad":"noc2"
    }},

    // Convert list array to stream of documents
    { $unwind: "$list" },

    // Add  (value1, value2, value3) for each list item 
    { $project: {
        _id: "$list.id",
        value: { $add: [ "$list.value1", "$list.value2", "$list.value3"] }
    }}
);
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "p45",
            "value" : 587
        },
        {
            "_id" : "p6",
            "value" : 47
        },
        {
            "_id" : "4578",
            "value" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Note that I've only aggregated using a single document for this example, and the output will be one result document for every item in the `list` array.

In real usage you may want to add an additional aggregation step to `$group` by document `_id` or some other criteria, depending on the outcome you are trying to achieve.